# Script to update website data on cron

Tags: ubuntu, cron, dns

I'm just starting to research an idea that I had to update a form on a website on a cron schedule.

The problem that I'm having is that I have a dynamic ip address and I would like my server to automatically update the ip address via html to my DNS provider (who doesn't support dynamic DNS like dyndns.org). So ideally, I would need to have a script that would be able to login to a website, update a form, and click the submit button.

Is this possible with any programming languages? This all has to be done via command line, as I'm using Ubuntu Server 10.04.

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very possible. A good place to start would be python with the httplib2 module.

http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/